# what is difference in 'The MAC is invalid' and 'The Payload is invalid' laravel?

Tags: laravel

I running two laravel 5.7 app, both have different app key.

```
 -->app 1 key 1,
 -->app 2 key 2
```

[This point is less imp] These are two app (different module based on user roles. uses different app keys, but accessing same db).

When encrypting some data in app 1 with key 1, now decrypt encrypted data in app 1 with key 1, Working properly.

But I change in encrypted data string (app 1, key 1) and trying to again decrypt in app 1 with key 1, it gives error "The payload is invalid". I digest this.

Now, the second thing is, I encrypt data in app 1 with key 1, and passed this encrypted data string in app 2 with key 2 for decryption it give another error "The MAC is invalid.".

Now my question is why laravel give two different error? why not it gives same error, because we send another data with another app (means this is wrong for second app).

Can you please differentiate. May it be cause to any security loop whole.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel encode and decode with base64 the playload. Here take a look :

```
/**
 * Get the JSON array from the given payload.
 *
 * @param  string  $payload
 * @return array
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException
 */
protected function getJsonPayload($payload)
{
    $payload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);

    // If the payload is not valid JSON or does not have the proper keys set we will
    // assume it is invalid and bail out of the routine since we will not be able
    // to decrypt the given value. We'll also check the MAC for this encryption.
    if (! $this->validPayload($payload)) {
        throw new DecryptException('The payload is invalid.');
    }

    if (! $this->validMac($payload)) {
        throw new DecryptException('The MAC is invalid.');
    }

    return $payload;
}


/**
 * Verify that the encryption payload is valid.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $payload
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validPayload($payload)
{
    return is_array($payload) && isset($payload['iv'], $payload['value'], $payload['mac']) &&
           strlen(base64_decode($payload['iv'], true)) === openssl_cipher_iv_length($this->cipher);
}


/**
 * Determine if the MAC for the given payload is valid.
 *
 * @param  array  $payload
 * @return bool
 */
protected function validMac(array $payload)
{
    $calculated = $this->calculateMac($payload, $bytes = random_bytes(16));

    return hash_equals(
        hash_hmac('sha256', $payload['mac'], $bytes, true), $calculated
    );
}
```

[Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php)

As you can see there is a double check, if you modify manually the payload it won't necessarily have the correct **structure** and will return `The payload is invalid`.

Then, when the payload is valid, it will try with the MAC. When the **content** doesn't match, it will return `The MAC is invalid.`